# Make BufferedReader not wait for Process to finish

Tags: java, process, bufferedreader

I got a process which runs under unix (shell-script). This script runs continuously and generates more output every second.

Now I tried to get the current output of it using the BufferedReader in Java. Now I realized that this one is waiting for the process to complete, so it's waiting forever.

How can I realize this otherwise? I just want to get the current output of a Process p as a String.

What I got until now:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./myScript.sh");
    InputStream stdin = p.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String returner = "";
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            returner += line;

        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println( "Processhandling went terribly wrong!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Regards, Flo

Comment: BufferedReader doesn't wait for the process to finish, but your while loop does. And if the process runs forever, what do you mean by "current output"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending each line you read onto an existing String.

Firstly, appending Strings like this is inefficient - you should use a StringBuilder, especially for large or numerous strings. Your method will get slower and slower (and eventually fill up all memory).

You keep appending forever (as long as there is input data), so as you say, it never completes.

You need to read a chunk of data (maybe a line at a time, but it depends on your data) and then process that chunk (possibly in another thread so that reading and processing can occur in parallel).

So instead of:

```
    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        returner += line;

    }
```

You need:

```
    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        processLine(line);
    }
```

Where `processLine()` does something useful with the data.

Comment: Your advice regarding using StringBuilder is totally right, but javac is, many times, "smart" enough to do it for you at the bytecode level.

Comment: The compiler will emit code that eventually produces a String, but is free to choose how. You can check what I'm saying for yourself.

Compile the following code:

    `public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "";
    for (final String arg : args) test += arg;
    System.out.println(args);
    }
    }`


Then decompile it doing `javap -c Test`. The compiler emitted a StringBuilder right? ;)

Comment: It does, yes! - but in that case why does code like the OP's written with String run many, many times slower (thousands?) than the code written explicitly with StringBuilder?

Comment: I'm not up to speed on reading bytecode, but code like the OPs seems to create a StringBuilder _on every iteration_ in order to join the old and new Strings - so this is still really slow comapred to creating a single StringBuilder outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting continuous output, the following code will run forever.

```
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    returner += line;

}
```

I'm not sure what you want exactly...If your script will run indefinitely, then your string will keep growing, the process will never return.

Answer (score 0):

Right now it will run forever, because there is no reason to stop.
If you add the following to you code, you might get where you wanted to go.

For example you could put a condition to stop like this:

```
boolean hasReachedGoal = false;
while ( !hasReachedGoal && (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    hasReachedGoal = line.contains("the string i was looking for")
    returner += line;
}
```